# InfluxDb Flux query is unexpectedly slow when multiple tables are returned

Tags: influxdb, flux

I am moving from InfluxDb 1.x to InfluxDb 2.x. The application shows a chart for min max and mean of measurements so I like to receive that information from one single query.

The query that I use is based on [this](https://community.influxdata.com/t/multiple-aggregations-min-mean-max-per-day/21762) example and look like this:

```
data = from(bucket: "my-bucket")
  |> range(start: 2022-09-01T00:00:00Z, stop: 2022-09-10T00:00:00Z)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "temperature")

valueMin = data 
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: min, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "min")  

valueMax = data 
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: max, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "min")  

valueAvg = data 
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "avg")
```

When I run the query for one output the query time is 0.04 seconds, but when I add another table the query time increases to 13(!) seconds.

The following query runs 0.04 seconds:

```
 data = from(bucket: "my-bucket")
  |> range(start: 2022-09-01T00:00:00Z, stop: 2022-09-10T00:00:00Z)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "temperature")

valueMin = data 
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: min, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "min")
```

While the next query takes 13 seconds:

```
data = from(bucket: "my-bucket")
  |> range(start: 2022-09-01T00:00:00Z, stop: 2022-09-10T00:00:00Z)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "temperature")

valueMin = data 
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: min, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "min")  

valueMax = data 
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: max, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "min")
```

What is wrong here / how can flux query response be improved?
I am currently on influxd version 2.6.1

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, you can try this, this might look stupid, but it's really fast.

```
valueMin = from(bucket: "my-bucket")
  |> range(start: 2022-09-01T00:00:00Z, stop: 2022-09-10T00:00:00Z)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "temperature") 
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: min, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "min")  

valueMax = from(bucket: "my-bucket")
  |> range(start: 2022-09-01T00:00:00Z, stop: 2022-09-10T00:00:00Z)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "temperature") 
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: max, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "min")  

valueAvg = from(bucket: "my-bucket")
  |> range(start: 2022-09-01T00:00:00Z, stop: 2022-09-10T00:00:00Z)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "temperature") 
  |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "avg")
```